# Calculating Electric Potential for a Thin Conducting Sphere?

Tags: electromagnetism

I am having a lot of trouble figuring out how to calculate the electric potential due to a thin spherical conductor of radius #R# with charge #Q#. My main problem is that if I take the initial potential to be 0 at infinity then by definition the potential is $V=-\int_{\infty}^{r}\vec{E}\cdot\ d\vec{s}$, in this case I can replace $d\vec{s}$ with $d\vec{r}$ and integrate along the radius but I'm confused about the electric field component since for $r<R$ there will be zero charged enclosed, hence by Gauss's law $E=0$, and then once $r>R$ charge will be enclosed so as you can see it varies. This is what is throwing me off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The electric field can be discontinuous and is indeed zero inside the sphere. You can continue integrating along your path from infinity, and when you get to the sphere, the field will drop to zero, and there is no longer a contribution to the potential. Therefore, the potential inside the sphere is the same as the potential on the shell, and is constant everywhere inside.

Comment: Very nice succinct answer!

Comment: In this case, phone posting actually helped :D